# In UCMA voicexml browser giving Runasync() method not supporting

Tags: c#, ucma

I am currently using UCMA 4.0 and implementing one sample that is based on IVR.
When I am running sample it's giving "Specified method is not supported."

I wrote following code for playing IVR on call.

```
public void playIVR()
    {
        Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.AudioVideo.VoiceXml.Browser voiceXmlBrowser = null;
        voiceXmlBrowser = new Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.AudioVideo.VoiceXml.Browser();
        vxmlDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "Voicexml");
        string vxmlURL = Path.Combine(vxmlDirectory, menuName.Trim().Replace(" ", "_") + ".vxml");
        Uri pageURI = new Uri(vxmlURL);
        voiceXmlBrowser.RunAsync(pageURI, null);
    }
```

When `voiceXmlBrowser.RunAsync(pageURI, null);` line hits, then it throws exception above mentioned.

Following is stack trace

"Specified method is not supported."

at Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.AudioVideo.SpeechSynthesisConnector.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)

at Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis.WaveOutputStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)

at Microsoft.Speech.Internal.SapiInterop.SpStreamWrapper.Seek(Int64 offset, Int32 seekOrigin, IntPtr plibNewPosition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like your voiceXmLBrowser has been connected to a call. Try calling `voiceXmlBrowser.SetAudioVideo(myAudioVideoCall)` before `RunAsync`.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for giving an answer. Now my sample is working and I figured out another problem, I had faced. Problem with rights given to the project folder.I given full access to the project folder and  than reinstalled UCMA 4.0. It might be VM's environment issue. Now sample is working fine.